# How to use "IdentityService and FormService" in Activiti7

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, activiti

How to use Activiti6 IdentityService and FormService in Activiti7

Foe Example Activiti6 Code:

```
@Resource
private IdentityService identityService;

public boolean login(String userName, String password) {
    return identityService.checkPassword(userName, password);
}

public Object getAllUser() {
    List<User> userList = identityService.createUserQuery().list();
    return toMyUser(userList);
}

public Object getAllGroup() {
    List<Group> groupList = identityService.createGroupQuery().list();
    List<UserGroup> userGroupList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Group group : groupList) {
        UserGroup userGroup = new UserGroup();
        userGroup.setId(group.getId());
        userGroup.setName(group.getName());
        userGroupList.add(userGroup);
    }
    return userGroupList;
}
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

These services are deprecated (removed) to make the engine light weight and cloud native, you can see the deprecation list from the [gitbook](https://activiti.gitbook.io/activiti-7-developers-guide/overview/previous)

Refer to the [identity management](https://activiti.gitbook.io/activiti-7-developers-guide/components/activiti-cloud-infrastructure/sso)

Answer (score 0):

these classes are removd in lastest version

define class then extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter to create yourself userDetailsService like this:
@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
auth.userDetailsService(dbUserDetailsService());
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).